# Can't reference static fields in Laravel Model's create method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have recently started learning Laravel and I'm trying to reference a static field, in this case $myUrls, in my Model's create method. This is what I'm trying to do but I keep getting the error:

> Undefined variable: myUrls

```
class myclass extends mySuperclass
{
 public static $myUrls= [ some data]

 public static function create( array $attributes = [] )
{

    $newObj = parent::create($attributes);
    $newObj->buildUrlLookups($newObj);
    return $newObj;
}

private function buildUrlLookups($newObj)
{  
    foreach ($newObj->$myUrls as $u) 
    {
    //some code
    }
}
```

I have also tried it with $this->myUrls and just $myUrls but non works.

Comment: `myUrls` isn't a attribute of `mySuperclass` object.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte you are right. Is there anyway I can reference it?

Comment: Directly, no. But in `foreach` you could use `foreach(self::myUrls as $u)`. Look at Jake answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
 foreach (self::$myUrls as $u)
```